# how to check vue components in browser without using VUE-Router library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, gulp, vuejs3

I am Using vue 3 with CLI Build tool. Going to import my component on .net page.
I need to check my components on browser without using a router library.  Actually it was stand alone components

Is there any way. In Vue 2 i have used gulp build tool and fractal tools for checking my components in broswer. After migrate to vue-3, i can't find solutions for that.

Comment: what do you mean by check components?

Answer (score 0):

If you route the page with Java or .Net, Just create a route page with .Net and import the component into your new page. Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to test a component and your vuejs project is starting rely on jsp or .net. just make a new route and import the component into the route page you make. you could see the way in vuejs.org quick start part. [https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools[enter](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx9R8.jpg)

Comment: Yeah it's fine. But i am trying to check without using the router library.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).